# Local Storage not working - dart

Tags: html, dart

I'm trying to create a program using dart that saves contacts from an html file.

This is my code in dart:

```
import 'dart:html';

void saveContact() {
  Storage localStorage = window.localStorage;

  var txtFirst = query("#firstname");
  String first = txtFirst.text;
  var txtLast = query("#lastname");
  String last = txtLast.text;
  var txtEmail = query("#email");
  String email = txtEmail.text;
  var txtMobile = query("#mobile");
  String mobile = txtMobile.text;
  var txtHome = query("#home");
  String home = txtHome.text;
  var txtOffice = query("#office");
  String office = txtOffice.text;

  var contact = {
    "firstname" : first,
    "lastname" : last,
    "email" : email,
    "mobile" : mobile,
    "home" : home,
    "office" : office
  };

  localStorage.setItem(first + " " + last, JSON.stringify(contact));
  var test2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(first + " " + last));
  var result = query("#divContents");
  result.text = test2.tostring();
}
void main() {
  querySelector('#savecontacts').onClick.listen(saveContact);
}
```

I wanted to output the contact in one of the divs just to see if the dart code worked. But nothing happens... Please help.

Comment: I haven't used localstorage myself yet, https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/lawndart might provide some ideas how to use it or this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062593/how-do-i-save-a-value-from-a-text-input-box-and-load-it-later-in-dart/12062594#12062594

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert' show JSON;

void saveContact() {
  Storage localStorage = window.localStorage;
  // (... as InputElement) isn't actually necessary,
  // it's just to silence the analyzer 
  var first = (querySelector("#firstname") as InputElement).value;
  var last = (querySelector("#lastname") as InputElement).value;
  var email = (querySelector("#email") as InputElement).value;
  var mobile = (querySelector("#mobile") as InputElement).value;
  var home = (querySelector("#home") as InputElement).value;
  var office = (querySelector("#office") as InputElement).value;

  var contact = {
    "firstname" : first,
    "lastname" : last,
    "email" : email,
    "mobile" : mobile,
    "home" : home,
    "office" : office
  };

  localStorage['$first $last'] = JSON.encode(contact);
  var test2 = JSON.decode(localStorage['$first $last']);
  var result = querySelector("#divContents");
  result.text = test2.toString();
}
void main() {
  querySelector('#savecontacts').onClick.listen((_) {
    saveContact();
    print('saved');
  });
}
```

The **HTML** I used for this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <!-- for this next line to work, your pubspec.yaml file must have a dependency on 'browser' -->
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>

    <input id="firstname">
    <input id="lastname">
    <input id="email">
    <input id="mobile">
    <input id="home">
    <input id="office">
    <button id="savecontacts">save</button>
    <div>
      <b>result</b>
      <div id="divContents"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Günter, but I tried it and there was still no output. Should I have anything installed? (I mean other than the Dart SDK and WebStorm)

Comment: No, that should be enough. I guess the problem is in your HTML. Maybe a missing or wrong Dart script tag. I can post my example but only in a few hours. I'm not on my computer. In the meantime you can add a few more print statements to figure out if the code is executed at all and if it does what you expect.